# Modified files in GIT staging area and in working directory at same time

Tags: git

I'm learning about GIT and the simple example given shows the basic cycle of adding files to the staging area, modifying them and adding again. At one point they show a case where a file is marked as **modified** in the staging area *and* in the working directory. The way I conceptualize it, I can't modify a file in the staging area, so I'm confused as how they did it. This is what I'm doing:

```
➜ touch one.txt
➜ git status -s
?? one.txt
➜ git add one.txt
➜ git status -s
A one.txt
➜ echo "test" > one.txt
➜ git status -s
AM one.txt
➜ echo "some modification" >> one.txt
➜ ~/Desktop/junky > git status -s
AM one.txt
```

So, how do you get a file to show up as modified in both areas? (i.e. that last line would be MM one.txt)

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: edit added: How do you get a file to show up as modified in both areas? (i.e. that last line would be `MM one.txt`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way to get `MM` is to commit the file, edit it, add it (staging) and edit it again.

Then Git will display `M` instead of `A` (it's no longer a new file) plus a second `M` for "this is modified in the workspace and not yet added"

Comment: Yes! This is a case of where not moving ahead when you don't understand is actually not beneficial. The reference I was reading didn't even talk about commits yet but was showing the result of something that needed to be covered to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `git add one.txt` you add `one.txt` to the staging area *as it is at that moment.*

Any changes you make after will make git mark your file as modified, but do not affect the staged version of the file. 
Therefore you have one `A` added version of the file (the version in the staging area) and one `M` modified version of the file (the version that is not staged).

To get `M` in both you could do this

```
echo 'test' >> test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -m "testing some stuff"
echo 'test2' >> test.txt
git add test.txt
echo 'test3' >> test.txt
```

After doing this you will have

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   test.txt
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   test.txt
```

Comment: That's what I do understand. The question is how do the examples I've seen online show files modified in both staging and working areas?

Comment: That is correct now. Unfortunately, I have to give the answer credit to Aaron since he replied accurately first. I appreciate your effort though.